# Nodejs oracle module error

Tags: node.js, oracle

Hey I am also getting the same error as you posted on the top...

```
Error: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

When I've set the Library path as mentioned:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then the strange ERROR:

`Segmentation fault (core dumped`)

What went wrong ? Please share your experience on this issue. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the response to running the following command in a terminal:

ls /opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/lib

Comment: Make sure you are using the same version of Oracle at build time as you are using at runtime.  Also, make sure that the Node process can actually access /opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to export: `ORACLE_HOME, LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before starting node.

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```